# How to create variable with for loop in php

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following php code where by a for loop create different variables. Basically what I need is, after run the code below, it should create different variables such as $o1, $o2, $o3 etc. But it is not working based on the way I implemented. Does anyone can help me how to solve this?

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $totalOa; $i++){
      '$o'.$i = $pieces[$i];  
}
```

Comment: You want to make an array or which type of output you want, please add your output which you want.

Comment: Not an array. It should create some variables

Comment: Why do you want to create variables? This is an antipattern. Use associative arrays; this is what they're for. Don't create variables dynamically.

Comment: @Anu As I understand you can make an array and use it like $o[$i] and use according to so I think it works same as string vars.

Comment: @Dharman Thank you for that suggestion. But for this particular situation, i don't wish to create array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this...**

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $totalOa; $i++){
     ${"o" . $i} = $pieces[$i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

You need to use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $totalOa; $i++){
    $o{$i} = $pieces[$i];  
}
```